# Remove list from list of lists if criterion is met

Tags: python, list, performance

I am looking to program a small bit of code in Python. I have a list of lists called "keep_list", from which I want to remove any sublist containing a specific value found in another list called "deleteNODE".

for example:

```
deleteNODE=[0,4]
keep_list=[[0,1,2],[0,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

After running the code the result should be (removing any list containing 0 or 4):

```
keep_list=[[1,2,3]]
```

Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
[x for x in keep_list if not set(x).intersection(deleteNODE)]
```

Since I thought the other answers were better, I also ran timeit on all the 3 answers and surprisingly this one was faster.

```
Python 3.8.2
>>> import timeit
>>>
>>> deleteNODE=[0,4]
>>> keep_list=[[0,1,2],[0,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>>
>>>
>>> def v1(keep, delete):
...     return [l for l in keep_list if not any(n in l for n in deleteNODE)]
...
>>> def v2(keep, delete):
...     return [i for i in keep_list if len(set(i)&set(deleteNODE)) == 0]
...
>>> def v3(keep, delete):
...     return [x for x in keep_list if not set(x).intersection(deleteNODE)]
...
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: v1(keep_list, deleteNODE), number=3000000)
7.2224646
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: v2(keep_list, deleteNODE), number=3000000)
7.1723587
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: v3(keep_list, deleteNODE), number=3000000)
5.640403499999998
```

I'm no Python expert so can anyone understand why mine was faster since it appears to be creating a new set for every evaluation?

Comment: I actually can't believe I didn't think of this for my answer. So, your solution is quicker than mine (the second one) because there are less computations. Both of ours grab the intersections of the lists. Mine calculates the length of the container and then evaluates the boolean of whether the length equals 0. Yours just evaluates the container as a boolean, which skips a whole step and is more efficient. Good eye!

Comment: Just lucky and I learned something new with your comment as well!

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using a list comprehension to cycle through each list within the larger list and by using sets. The `&` operator between sets returns the intersection (the elements common between both sets). Therefore, if the intersection between the list you're evaluating and `deleteNODE` is not zero, that means there is a common element and it gets excluded.

```
keep_list = [i for i in keep_list if len(set(i)&set(deleteNODE)) == 0]
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Additionally, is there a way to adapt this to ignore the first index of every list? eg. check only keep_list[1],keep_list[2] and keep_list[3]

Comment: instead of ```keep_list```, you would just do ```keep_list[1:0]``` and it will grab everything other than the first list.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I want it to iterate in every list but only on items 1,2 and 3. Eg to ignore keep_list[i][0] for all lists.

Comment: Then you would use the same technique but change the index to be on the individual lists instead of the list of lists. e.g.: ```[i for i in keep_list if not set(i[1:0).intersection(deleteNODE)]```

(Note that this is using the condition that Marcelus Trojahn gave)

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using list comprehension

```
deleteNODE=[0,4]
keep_list=[[0,1,2],[0,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
...
keep_list = [l for l in keep_list if not any(n in l for n in deleteNODE)]
```